# Why SimpleDateFormat does not throw exception for invalid format?

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

```
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("23-06-2015"));
    }
}
```

why this returns `Sun Dec 05 00:00:00 GMT 28` I am expecting an exception.

Comment: You cannot get date Object from a String Date in a formatted state. Hence when u tried to format the date, JVM irrespective of your format gave you a generic date.

Comment: Try it instead: ` java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("23-06-2015");`, if you are using Java8.

Comment: Because `SimpleDateFormat` was designed this way. It has turned out to be a poor design decision. You may get your expected exception if you call `setLenient(false)` on your `SimpleDateFormat` before parsing. But the good solution is the one @sndyuk suggests: skip `SimpleDateFormat` completely and use `DateTimeFormatter`. If you are not yet using Java 8, you can get it in the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("23-06-201abc5xyz")` also will be parsed fine!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat` has this to say about repeated pattern letters:

> Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. **For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored** unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields

(Emphasis mine)

So *for parsing*, `"yyyy-MM-dd"` is equivalent to `"y-M-d"`.

With this pattern, `"23-06-2015"` is parsed as `year = 23, month = 6, dayOfMonth = 2015`.

By default, this gets resolved by starting at 1st June 0023, and counting 2015 days forward, taking you to 5th December 0028.

You can change this behaviour with `SimpleDateFormat.setLenient(false)` -- with leniency disabled, it will throw an exception for out-of-range numbers. This is properly documented in `Calendar.setLenient()`

---

Note, for new code in Java 8, it's a good idea to avoid the old `Date` and `Calendar` classes. Use `LocalDateTime.parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` if you can.

Comment: Also if to read the JavaDoc for `parse` method in a `DateFormat` class you can see next: *By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).*

Comment: @slim Thanks for suggestion for DateTimeFormatter